Create a Grading Chart with Conditional Formating in Sheets
I have created a Grading Chart where I want to add in my student's assignments and then highlight the rows with conditional formatting to match their grade per assignment.
I was trying a match formula to match the grade in Cell B107 to A4:A104. I count all the cells below the number to be colored in.
So I tried a count formula that got me closer to what I wanted. Here is the formula I tried.
=COUNTIF($A$4:$A$104, B106) <1
This one worked but if I change the number they received it is not working like I want. See the screenshots below.
In the conditional formatting, I have tried a match and a count if.
I want the cells to be colored in on the chart above each assignment where the points earned match the grade in row A4:A104

Please always include a formatted text table with your sample data and expected output.

You can try with the following formula:
=$A5<=B$107

It should be entered as the custom formula when applying conditional formatting to the entire B5:M105 range.


This worked out perfectly! I knew it was something simple. Thank you so much
